# Supporting multiple language in my app

Tags: android, localization

I want make support of my application English, Hindi, Urdu.
For that I created two values strings folders like values-hi,values-ur then default strings.xml for English  when I click on Urdu I need to load Urdu strings file for all labels and make UI RTL support.

Comment: and what is a problem?

Comment: How to load strings file of Urdu ?and update local Lang to urdu

Comment: it does it automatically. You only need to switch to the Urdu language in device settings

Comment: IF the intent is to load urdu while rest of the phone is not, then it becomes not so simple. it's possible with some trickery while loading the resources.

as for changing phone to urdu, go to your settings, language options and choose urdu as the default language. if you don't have that, change firmware to one that has. if you can't do that try some language change apps from google play if they work on your phone(they worked with older android phones for testing stuff like this).

Comment: I willl not change from device settings manually I want from button click on my project

Comment: Then simply switch the app locale programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue using some sort of ContextWrapper to force the language in any activity.

The ContextWrapper code is:

```
public class ContextWrapper extends android.content.ContextWrapper {

public ContextWrapper(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, Locale newLocale) {

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = res.getConfiguration();

    if (BuildUtils.isAtLeast24Api()) {
        configuration.setLocale(newLocale);

        LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(newLocale);
        LocaleList.setDefault(localeList);
        configuration.setLocales(localeList);

        context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);

    } else if (BuildUtils.isAtLeast17Api()) {
        configuration.setLocale(newLocale);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);

    } else {
        configuration.locale = newLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(configuration, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    return new ContextWrapper(context);
}
```

}

You have to inherit attachBaseContext lifecycle callback in each activity you want to force the language, eg.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(ContextWrapper.wrap(base, Locale.ENGLISH));
}
```

Obviously if you want to change language even in the current activity you have to reload it.